# UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown error -2147483648 when try initialise camera device using samsung camera sdk

Tags: android, android-camera, samsung-mobile, android-camera2, samsung-s8

I am using samsung camera sdk to use camera apis.My applications Camera is working fine except the Samsung S8+ and S9. These 2 mention device is unable to start the camera device on.

Getting the following errors:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.xxx.xx/com.xxx.xx.VideoActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown error -2147483648
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity + 4008(ActivityThread.java:4008)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity + 4040(ActivityThread.java:4040)
       at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute + 51(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState + 145(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute + 70(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1948(ActivityThread.java:1948)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 106(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 214(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7045(ActivityThread.java:7045)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 493(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 964(ZygoteInit.java:964)

Caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown error -2147483648
       at com.samsung.android.sdk.camera.impl.internal.NativeUtil.a + 452(SourceFile:452)
       at com.samsung.android.sdk.camera.impl.internal.NativeUtil.setSurfaceFormat + 165(SourceFile:165)
       at com.samsung.android.sdk.camera.impl.processor.EffectProcessorImpl28.initialize + 315(SourceFile:315)
       at com.uipl.cleardoc.VideoActivity.initProcessor + 876(VideoActivity.java:876)
       at com.uipl.cleardoc.VideoActivity.openCameraSamsung + 970(VideoActivity.java:970)
       at com.uipl.cleardoc.VideoActivity.onResume + 2608(VideoActivity.java:2608)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume + 1412(Instrumentation.java:1412)
       at android.app.Activity.performResume + 7558(Activity.java:7558)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity + 4000(ActivityThread.java:4000)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity + 4040(ActivityThread.java:4040)
       at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute + 51(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState + 145(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute + 70(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1948(ActivityThread.java:1948)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 106(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 214(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7045(ActivityThread.java:7045)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 493(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 964(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

Can anyone have any idea why this crash is happening ?